# Display text notes data from a database and modify them to save them again with NodeJs and MySql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I am writing a small website and I am at the last step, indeed my site allows a user to register then to connect, write text notes in a text area , save them in a database, this last step is : if I click on the button view my notes, I must have a page with a list of the saved notes, and if I click on a note in the list, the note appears in a text area , allowing me to modify it if I want and to save it again. I'm on nodejs and I looked for how to do this last step and I didn't find it. Ps : my table in the database have that form : textMemo|User  .

Answer (score 0):

you can use LONGTEXT datatype column. that can store 4GB data of characters.